# How to detect internet disconnection on SSL/TCP sockets which were connected before?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, ssl, tcp

I am having a thread which blocks on `select()` based `SSL_read()`. The main thread writes whenever needed using `SSL_write()`. During unit testing, I found a problem:

- Client TCP socket `connect()` to server on SSL(TLS)
- After sometime, disable internet
- Write some data on client TCP/SSL socket

Even without interenet, the `SSL_write()` returns the correct number of bytes written, instead of 0 or some error. Such interenet disconnections are arbitrary, neither too high nor too low.

My expectation is that, whenever there is an internet disconnection, the socket should generate some interesting event, which is detectable and I will discontinue the socket + SSL connections.
In case I have to establish some client-server hand made protocol, then that's possible.

What is the best way to achieve such internet detection?
Expecting a solution with lesser CPU cycles & lesser client server communication. I am sure that, this is not a very special problem and hence must have been solved before.

[P.S.: The client sockets are opened on mobile platforms like Android & iOS, however I would like to know a general solution.]

Comment: A simple and dirty way would be to try to connect to Google before using the socket. If you fail to connect, then there's a problem

Comment: So your program first connects to server, then _waits_ (why?) and only then tries to `SSL_write` into the previously opened socket? The question is: why? You should probably `connect` and then start communication immediately. If you do that and the connection disappears in a matter of milliseconds before you try to `SSL_write`, then you can make the server respond to each piece of data sent and then check whether the client got this confirmation or not.

Answer (score 3):

This is general problem with sockets. You can't have a certified delivery with them. If you want to know if the counterparty is indeed reachable, you have to implement some sort of hearbeats yourself.

Generally successful write to the socket is no indication of availability of the recepient on the other end.

Comment: 2 comments: For TCP, you can enable TCP keepalives on the socket to get notified of connectivity problems. Usually though, protocol layer keepalives are more flexible. 2nd comment, on e.g. Linux, you can use getsockopt (TCP_INFO ...) to know if a write/send of data has been ACKed.

Comment: @ErikAlapää, keep alives will only give you an indication after keepalife timeout, so again, successful single write is not a guarantee. And TCP_INFO will not neccessarily work fine - absence of the ACK is no indication of failed delivery.

Comment: Keepalive timeout can be adjusted. And prolongued absence if ACK can be used to detect connectivity problems, that is obvious.

Comment: @ErikAlapää, did you succeed in building a robust disconnect detection within application based on TCP_INFO data?

Comment: Using TCP_INFO is what it is - an unportable way of detecting if there are outstanding ACKs on the socket. An ACK is not an indication of the receving application having done anything, of course. In my case, I use it to detect if linux pmtu discovery has stopped sending probes. For detecting connection loss, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227007/howto-detect-that-a-network-cable-has-been-unplugged-in-a-tcp-connection