# QTcpSocket Keep alive option does not work

Tags: sockets, keep-alive, linux-mint, qtcpsocket

I have a simple program as my client consisting a tcp socket (QTcpSocket). Codes for my client are given below:

```
while (tcpSocket.data()->waitForConnected(maxWaitingTimeToConnect) == false)
{
    tcpSocket.data()->connectToHost(serverIP, serverPort);
    if (maxRetryNumberToConnect != -1 && retryNumber++ > maxRetryNumberToConnect)
    {
        qDebug() << "Socket is disconnected and maximum try for re-connection reached.";
        return false;
    }
    emit sgl_tryToConnect();
    // Socket is disconnected and trying to re-connect
    QThread::msleep(100);
}
qDebug() << "Client is connected";
qDebug() << tcpSocket.data()->localPort();
auto sd = tcpSocket.data()->socketDescriptor();
NetworkShared::setSocketOption(&sd);
```

which setSocketOption is also given below:

```
/// Set keepAlive
int enableKeepAlive = 1;
/* Set socket FD's option OPTNAME at protocol level LEVEL
   to *OPTVAL (which is OPTLEN bytes long).
   Returns 0 on success, -1 for errors.  */
qDebug() << setsockopt(*socketDescriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &enableKeepAlive, sizeof(enableKeepAlive));

int maxIdle = 1; /// Seconds
qDebug() << setsockopt(*socketDescriptor, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &maxIdle, sizeof(maxIdle));

int count = 1;  /// Send up to 1 keepalive packets out, then disconnect if no response
qDebug() << setsockopt(*socketDescriptor, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &count, sizeof(count));

int interval = 1;  /// Send a keepalive packet out every 1 seconds (after the 1 second idle period)
qDebug() << setsockopt(*socketDescriptor, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &interval, sizeof(interval));
```

when I run my program, everything is look fine and keepalive option will be enabled for my socket. But it does not work when I unplug my cable on client side. I have brought my netstat output below which incdicate that keepalive timer has enabled for my socket.

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.157:37281     192.168.2.163:4444      ESTABLISHED keepalive (0.16/0/0)
```

I have also enabled keepalive option on server side exactly like client side. Now I have some questions; 1- When I should enable keepalive option? After connecting to server or before connecting? 2- Should I write some code for catching keepalive error in my program?

By the way, my program is running in linux mint 17.1 and I also changed keeplalive options in sysctl.conf and proc/sys to no vail.

Thanks in advance for your helps.
Reza

Comment: The `netstat` output you have posted indicates that it does work. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect internet disconnection on SSL/TCP sockets which were connected before?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116838/how-to-detect-internet-disconnection-on-ssl-tcp-sockets-which-were-connected-bef)

Comment: Have you referred this [QAbstractSocket::disconnected () signal does not emit when switch is disconnected](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-29469.html). As an alternative, you may also think of using various `waitfor...()` methods (i.e. `waitForReadyRead(milliseconds)`). The timeout can be set to desirable amount and during then also check if the connection is alive. BTW, I am new to Qt. Did you find solution to your actual problem? @EJP, I think the OP has a problem where the socket doesn't get disconnected even when internet plug is pulled out (if I understood correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to use Qt's function [setSocketOption](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#setSocketOption):

```
your_socket->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::KeepAliveOption, 1);
```

> **enum QAbstractSocket::SocketOption**
>
> This enum represents the options that can be set on a socket. If
>   desired, they can be set after having received the connected() signal
>   from the socket or after having received a new socket from a
>   QTcpServer.
>
> **Note:** On Windows Runtime, QAbstractSocket::KeepAliveOption must be set before the socket is connected.

and for catch any connection errors:

```
connect (your_socket, static_cast<void (QTcpSocket::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)>(&QAbstractSocket::error), this, &YourClass::onError);
// ...

void YourClass::onError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError)
{
    switch(socketError)
    {
        case QAbstractSocket::ConnectionRefusedError:
        // ...
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better why?

Comment: @EJP, because Qt has its own functions for that, and it is strange to mix Qt and system functions in that case. Also Qt is a cross-platform framework

Comment: Irrelevant. If `setsockopt()` doesn't return -1 it has clearly worked, so how exactly is this going to solve the OP's problem?

Comment: setsocket return 0 which means it's true. I also try setSocketOption provided by Qt but it did not solve my problem. Also how can I set other options such as idle time with this function? It only enable keepalive option.

Comment: @VladimirBershov I also connect socket error exactly like your suggested code but it does not work in my case. When I unplug my cable, server understand it but client side does not. I think my problem is the values that I set for my socket.

Comment: @Reza There is nothing on this page that suggests you have a problem at all, and I said so an hour ago. You need to address that.

Comment: @EJP I think I said my problem clearly. My socket on client side does not understand dead connection due to unplugging of network cable. I can catch other socket errors before and after plugging again. So I am almost sure that my code is correct. Please take a look at netstat output keepalive (0.16/0/0). When I unplug my cable, the first number start to count down and the third number start to count up. But the second parameter is always zero. Is it okay?

Comment: @VladimirBershov thanks for showing me how to connect error signal, I could not connect it before.