# how does cassandra server identifies crashed client connections?

Tags: cassandra

How does cassandra server running in windows operating system identifies if any connection disconnected abnormally by Client, so that it closes the connection and allows for any new connection if ***native_transport_max_concurrent_connections*** property set.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227007/howto-detect-that-a-network-cable-has-been-unplugged-in-a-tcp-connection

Comment: @Raedwald, If the server was developed by us, we can identify crashed client connections. Here my doubt is how Cassandra Server identifies these type of connections to give chance for new connections.

Comment: Yes. The linked question shows the methods available to a server such as Cassandra. That is why I said only "see also", and did not vote to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

In the cassandra.cluster file there should be a idle_heartbeat_interval config property.  This says how often it will ping the clients to see if they are still active.  If a client is not still active, it should close the connection.

https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html

Comment: This the python driver which closes idle connections automatically. I'm asking about how Cassandra Server closes wrong connections (For example when client crashes, so it does not close connection).