# How to Determine if Ethernet Cable Has Been Unplugged During Runtime

Tags: stm32, ethernet

*Update: Cube has Status and Link callbacks. Have not tried them yet but I expect that is the best solution

I am using the Ethernet peripheral on my `STM32F429ZI` with the

**LWIP Middleware generated by CubeMX**

. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227007/howto-detect-that-a-network-cable-has-been-unplugged-in-a-tcp-connection) is similar but for PC.

I find it hard to understand the Ethernet section in the product specs. It is not obvious what registers I could watch to check for downed links.

I also looked into the **LWIP** code in case there was an obvious non-register-watching approach to this. In the main loop it polls the network interface with `MX_LWIP_Process`. On read it knows if there is a packet via the following:

```
void ethernetif_input(struct netif *netif)
{
  err_t err;
  struct pbuf *p;

  /* move received packet into a new pbuf */
  p = low_level_input(netif);

  /* no packet could be read, silently ignore this */
  if (p == NULL) return;
```

On send, the `tcp_output()` function is very cumbersome. It has errors for invalid netif, invalid local_ip and a general error that I could watch but nothing that directly tells me that the link is down.

My last thought is that the Ethernet headers have LED's that turn off if a cable is unplugged. I am going to look at the hardware diagrams for the STM32F4 DK's to see if I can watch those.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can with callback.

All you need is to do :

1-) Enable LWIP_NETIF_LINK_CALLBACK definition inside lwipopts.h file.
By default, the value can be 0. Check it.

2-) Initialize " netif_set_link_callback(netif, ethernetif_update_config); " in void ethernetif_input(struct netif *netif) function.

3-) Read PHY register and do whatever want.

See my example, if the ethernet cable is disconnected and reconnected, the system will reset itself.

```c
void ethernetif_input(struct netif *netif)
{
    err_t err;
    struct pbuf *p;
 
    /* move received packet into a new pbuf */
    p = low_level_input(netif);
    uint32_t regvalue = 0;
    netif_set_link_callback(netif, ethernetif_update_config); //added by Volkan
    // Read PHY link status

    if (HAL_ETH_ReadPHYRegister(&EthHandle, PHY_BSR, &regvalue) == HAL_OK)
    {
        if((regvalue & PHY_LINKED_STATUS)== (uint16_t)RESET) 
        {
            // Link status = disconnected
            if (netif_is_link_up(netif))
            {
                netif_set_down(netif);
                printf("unplugged\r\n");
                netif_set_link_down(netif);
            }
        } else {
            // Link status = connected
            if (!netif_is_link_up(netif))
            {
                printf("plugged\r\n");
                NVIC_SystemReset();
            }
        }
    }
    /* no packet could be read, silently ignore this */
    if (p == NULL) return;
    
    /* entry point to the LwIP stack */
    err = netif->input(p, netif);
    
    if (err != ERR_OK)
    {
        LWIP_DEBUGF(NETIF_DEBUG, ("ethernetif_input: IP input error\n"));
        pbuf_free(p);
        p = NULL;
    }
}
```

That's all.